# Loop through JSON object and values to List in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to get values from a JSON object and save them into 2 lists. I am struggling with understanding how to loop through the JSON object to get the JSON array values.

I believe I am Deserializing correctly, but I am stuck going forward. Here is what I currently have

```
JObject jsonResult =  {"foodtype": ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Bread"], 
               "drinks": ["Coke", "Root Beer"]}


 public class Rootobject
  {
    public string[] foodType { get; set; }
    public string[] drinks { get; set; }
  }

var allObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonResult.ToString());
```

What I am wanting is for 2 lists to be generated from the JSON result like so:

```
List<string> food = new List<string> {Pizza, Pasta, Bread}
List<string> drink = new List<string> {Coke, Root Beer}
```

Comment: `DeserializeObject` can only produce _one_ object. Are you fine with having a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of a `Rootobject`?

Comment: you already have two list of string but inside encapsulated as properties of a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid, the snippet below is incorrect:

```
JObject jsonResult =  {"foodtype": ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Bread"], 
               "drinks": ["Coke", "Root Beer"]}
```

You need to have a string which can be deserialized.

The code below should help you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objectToSerialize = new Rootobject()
    {
        Drinks = new [] {"Coke", "Root Beer" },
        FoodType = new[] { "Pizza", "Pasta", "Bread" }
    };

    var serializedByTheLib = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

    string jsonResult =
        "{ \"foodtype\": [\"Pizza\", \"Pasta\", \"Bread\"], \"drinks\": [\"Coke\", \"Root Beer\"] }";

    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonResult);
}


public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("foodType")]
    public string[] FoodType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("drinks")]
    public string[] Drinks { get; set; }
}
```

Key concepts:

- An object can be serialized to JSON
- A JSON string can be deserialized to an Object

Take a look at [newtonsoft documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) to get more info

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

When you have deserialized the json string to your `Rootobject`, you can just pick the properties of it:

```
string json = "{\"foodtype\": [\"Pizza\", \"Pasta\", \"Bread\"], \"drinks\": [\"Coke\", \"Root Beer\"]}";
Rootobject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
List<string> food = rootObject.foodType.ToList();
List<string> drinks = rootObject.drinks.ToList();
```